# How do I add a variable inside an object using setUser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to set the 'keys' variable inside a set function.

The 'keys' variable will not pass as the key

How do I go about passing the variable keys as the key inside of this object?

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({
  key: 'value',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: 'value3'
})

const passwordChange = (keys, elem) => {
  setUser({...user, keys: elem})
}

passwordChange(key3, 'new value')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({
  key: 'value',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: 'value3'
})

const passwordChange = (keys, elem) => {
  setUser({...user, [keys]: elem})
}

passwordChange('key3', 'new value')
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned 'keys' inside object will consider as a string.
So you need to modify function as below.

```
const passwordChange = (keys, elem) => {
    let cUser = user;
    cUser[keys] = elem;
    setUser(cUser);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the previous value and update the key with new value

```
 const passwordChange = (keys, elem) => {
    setUser((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        [keys]: elem,
      };
    });
  };
```